# SQL - uniqueidentifier in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SSMS v18.

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Azure RTM 12.0.200.8

I have 3500 unique identifiers to compare or to keep in where clause.

```
select * 
from tableName
where columnName in ('6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA',
                     '7C59FC31-SA87-1667-B31D-00DD010772DA'
                     .
                     .
                     .
                    )
```

`columnName` is unique identifier here.

Like this I have 3500 unique identifiers to compare in where clause.

I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character to uniqueidentifier

when I use `convert(nvarchar(36, columnName))` in query - the query keeps running for 5 minutes but doesn't return any results.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? That error indicates the string provided can't be converted into a guid. You will need to correct the offending value(s). It might be a better option to instead insert your 3500 values into a table, and use a JOIN instead of torturing your server with a 3500 value `IN`. It'll likely be easier to maintain, as well.

Comment: when I use convert(nvarchar(36,columnName) in query  - Query keeps running for 5 minutes but dont give any result

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Microsoft SQL Azure RTM 12.0.200.8

Comment: **#1** is missing.

Comment: You obvously have a typo somewhere in your data. Insert the data into a table and use `try_cast` to find the offending value(s)

Comment: If you provide us with a [mre] we (and you) will likely spot the odd one(s) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Overall, casting to a proper data type was missing.

`VARCHAR(...)` data type is not a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
INSERT INTO @tbl (col) VALUES
(TRY_CAST('6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)),
(TRY_CAST('C49CBB38-2C1E-43DE-8A9D-3DECB6B4F183' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER));
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE TRY_CAST(col AS VARCHAR(40)) in
(
    '6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA',
    '7C59FC31-SA87-1667-B31D-00DD010772DA'
);

-- Method #2
SELECT t.*
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN
   (VALUES
      ('6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA'),
      ('7C59FC31-SA87-1667-B31D-00DD010772DA')
   ) AS UniqueIDs(col)
ON t.col = TRY_CAST(UniqueIDs.col AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
in those 3500 values you can add a prefix for below
```

```
    select * 
    from tableName
    where 
       columnName in
                  (
                    SELECT 
                         CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA'),
                   SELECT 
                        CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'7C59FC31-SA87-1667-B31D-00DD010772DA')
    .
    .
    .
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it using format below -

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName IN (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA') UNION ALL
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '7C59FC31-SA87-1667-B31D-00DD010772DA')
    -- Add more SELECT statements for the remaining unique identifiers
)
```

Comment: Just check my answer. It is much more concise.